# Export data to excel file

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5

```
 **i want to export 100data from database but every sheet must have just 12 data **
```

i'm using maatwebsite package for my laravel application

```
$data = array();
        $data['usertotal']      = DB::table('users')
                                ->join('employees', 'users.id', '=', 'employees.user_id')
                                ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name', 'employees.function', 'employees.salary')
                                ->skip($j)
                                ->take(12)
                                ->get();
```

//this is my code with maatwebsite package
/* Start Exporting Data */

```
   Excel::load($sourceFilePath, function ($excel) use ($data)  {
         $excel->sheet('CNSS 2T19', function($sheet) use($data) {
         $datasheet = array();

         $i=0;
         foreach($data['total-user'] as $datanew){
                    $datasheet[$i] = array( $datanew['first_name'].' '.$datanew['last_name'],
                    $datanew['chez_emp'],
                    $datanew['cat_prof'],

                    $datanew['brut_1'],
                    $datanew['brut_2'],
                    $datanew['brut_3'],
                    $datanew['total'],

                );
            $i++;
         }
```

Comment: first , can you get you data in **$data['usertotal']**  ?

Comment: 100/12 not possible!!!

Comment: yes i get it data with success

Comment: i need to add 12 data by sheet and the rest in the last sheet

Answer (score 0):

you should use (offset , limit) and each loop add 12 to offset like this:

```
$data = array();
        $data['usertotal']      = DB::table('users')
                                ->join('employees', 'users.id', '=', 'employees.user_id')
                                ->select('users.first_name','users.last_name', 'employees.function', 'employees.salary')
                                ->offset($j+12)
                                ->limit(12)
                                ->get();
```